# Xcode 12.5 compiler bug, 'nil' cannot be used in context expecting type 'someType'

Tags: swift, conditional-operator, xcode12.5

What's the difference between these two code snippets?

```
cellModels.append(contentsOf: [].compactMap { $0.condition ? .init(text: $0.text, backgroundColor: $0.color, action: $0.action) : nil })


cellModels.append(contentsOf: [].compactMap {
            if $0.condition {
                return .init(text: $0.text, backgroundColor: $0.color, action: $0.action)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        })
```

After updating to Xcode 12.5, first code doesn't compile anymore

Some code snippet for Playground. Try it in Xcode 12.5

```
struct SomeStruct {
var str: String
}
var arr1: [SomeStruct] = []
arr1.append(contentsOf: ["123123", "2", "332", "124r132q", "123"].compactMap { $0.count == 3 ? .init(str: $0) : nil })
arr1.append(contentsOf: ["123123", "2", "332", "124r132q", "123"].compactMap {
                if $0.count == 3 {
                    return .init(str: $0)
                } else {
                    return nil
                }})
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: It might be because the ternary statement is complex for it to read. It just compiles and works as expected when I try splitting the code into two parts 

`var mappedArray: [SomeStruct] = ["123123", "2", "332", "124r132q", "123"].compactMap { $0.count == 3 ? .init(str: $0) : nil }
 arr1.append(contentsOf: mappedArray)`

Comment: @Nina That works, according to the OP; you should probably give it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting code into two parts helped

```
var mappedArray: [SomeStruct] = ["123123", "2", "332", "124r132q", "123"].compactMap { $0.count == 3 ? .init(str: $0) : nil }

arr1.append(contentsOf: mappedArray)
```

Comment: That is Nina's comment. You should let Nina give it as an answer so you can accept it and award reputation.

Comment: If Nina answer, I’ll delete mine

Comment: No problem, as long as it helps 